# How did the U.S.S.R manage to rotate the N-1 from horizontal to vertical?

Tags: history, soviet-union, n-1

The title says it all - but I heard that NASA considered horizontal integration for the Saturn V couldn't be considered, as lifting the rocket to a vertical position would require an immense engineering effort to prevent sagging or damage while lifting, as well as simply moving such a large object into the launch position. So how / what mechanisms did the Soviets use to achieve this with the N-1, a similarly sized launch vehicle?

Comment: The russian rocket engineers had experiences in rotating the R-7 rocket from horizontal to vertical. The german V-2 was rotated too when launched from mobile launch facilities during WWII. The V-2 transported to the USSR as spoils of war were moved in horizontal position.

Comment: It's not just the method, it's also the design of the rocket.  I expect the N-1 was *designed* with the constraint that it would be rotated onto the pad and consideration would have been given to the structural design to allow it to withstand that mission phase.  The Saturn V, naturally, was not, and designing a system to rotate it after the fact would have been burdensome largely *because* it had not been designed with that requirement in mind.

Comment: @Uwe the V-2 was not so much rotated as hoisted. Attach a cable to the top and lift it using a crane...

Comment: @jwenting that's incorrect https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meillerwagen

Answer (score 34, accepted):

They used an extremely large rail-based transporter/erector nicknamed the "grasshopper".

[image]

[Image source](https://live.staticflickr.com/4056/5159623725_bf34342d65_b.jpg)

This image shows the N-1 in the process of rotation.

[image]

[Image source](https://live.staticflickr.com/1330/5160263794_549fe8314b_b.jpg)

[russianspaceweb](http://www.russianspaceweb.com/baikonur_energia_history.html) says the hydraulic ram visible in this image "boasted a hydraulic cylinder one meter in caliber, which had a length of nine meters and would extend up to 16 meters". Two pairs of these rams were employed per Grasshopper.

This [page](https://www.360cities.net/image/transporter-erectors-grasshopper-baikonur) states that the Grasshoppers were rebuilt and used for the Energia/Buran.

Comment: If a load is too heavy and wide to be transported on a single railway track, it may be transported on three parallel tracks.

Comment: "boasted a hydraulic cylinder one meter in caliber" Is caliber here a technical term or a translation error? Diameter I'd understand.

Comment: I'm surprised they got it done with such a relatively small installation. Considering it's made in the 60's, I had expected an even larger installation. They must've had some experienced engineers indeed.

Comment: @Uwe two tracks http://www.buran.ru/images/jpg/bbur182.jpg

Comment: @Mast I assume it's "caliber" as in the diameter of the barrel of a gun, which is a cylinder. Though I don't know if that jargon applies here.

Comment: @Uwe And you can even leave the tracks out. For example, take a look at the Saturn/Apollo/spaceshuttle crawler-transporters.

Comment: According to [this source](http://bastion-karpenko.ru/n-1-okb-1/), the name of the transporter/erector (literal translation from Russian - "installer") was 11U25 (11У25). It was designed by [CKBTM](https://ckbtm.org/produktsiya/kosmicheskaya-produktsiya/tua-11u25-dlya-rkn-n1/) (ЦКБТМ) corporation. The unit wasn't self propelled, instead it was transported by diesel locomotives on two standard gauge railway tracks. V. Pavlov was leading engineer for the installer project.

Comment: @Mast I think "caliber" is just a translation infelicity. "Diameter" might have been a better choice.

Comment: @Mast caliber is the inner diameter of a bore, it makes sense in this application.Its most likely the direct translation

Comment: @DatsunZ1 I thought that was only used as such with guns and cannons. Thank you for the clarification.

Comment: @Uwe: The problem is not the weight of the rocket, but its structural strength.  It has to be built strong enough to keep from buckling in the middle when it's horizontal, which adds weight.

Comment: @jamesqf The rocket is transported and rotated to vertical without the liquid fuel. Much less weight than when launched and only at 1 g. But in flight just before stage separation the rocket should resist 3 or 4 g.

Comment: @Uwe: Yes, I understand that it would be fueled after being erected.  But it's a matter of engineering: if it's horizontal, it has to be able to resist sideways forces, as well as forces along the axis.  The fuel & pressurization actually makes the structure stronger: think of trying to crush a full soda can vs an empty one.  Or putting weight on one standing up vs one laying on its side.